# What is an example of a non-mixed $\ell$-adic sheaf?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, etale-cohomology, perverse-sheaves

$\def\FF{\mathbb{F}}\def\cG{\mathcal{G}}\def\QQ{\mathbb{Q}}\def\CC{\mathbb{C}}$I've been attending a reading seminar at Michigan on Kiehl and Weissauer's book [Weil conjectures, perverse sheaves and l’adic Fourier transform](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-662-04576-3). We spend a lot of time proving sheaves are mixed, and I've just realized we haven't seen any non-mixed ones!

I'll repeat the definitions in case there is ambiguity. Let $X_0$ be a variety over $\FF_q$, with $X$ the base change to an algebraic closure $\FF_q$. I also want $X_0$ to be normal, see discussion below. Let $\cG$ an $\ell$-adic sheaf on $X_0$. Let $\tau: \overline{\QQ_{\ell}} \to \CC$ be an embedding. A sheaf is called $\tau$-pure of weight $\beta$ if, for every closed point $x$ of $X_0$, the eigenvalues $(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_r)$ of Frobenius acting on the stalk $\cG_x$ obey $|\tau(\alpha_i)|^2 = q^{d(x) \beta}$, where $d(x)$ is the extension degree $[k(x):\FF_q]$. A sheaf is called $\tau$-mixed if it has a filtration whose subquotients are $\tau$-pure.

I'm fairly sure I can show that, if such an example exists, then it can be found with $\cG$ irreducible and smooth of rank $r$ and $X_0$ a curve (and, if there is an example where $X_0$ is normal, then there is an example where $X_0$ is a smooth curve). So we just need to write down a continuous irreducible representation of $\pi_1(X_0) \cong \pi_1(X) \rtimes \widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ where either (a) the Frobenius conjugacy class at some point of $X_0$ acts by two eigenvalues with different archimedean norm or (b) there are two different points of $X_0$ whose Frobenius conjugacy classes act with elements of different norms. And $\pi_1(X)$ could be something as nice as the profinite free group on $2$ generators, which is really easy to make representations of.

But I can't figure out how to make my representation extend to the semidirect product.

---

What if $X_0$ is not normal? Then we can build an example as follows: Take a nodal cubic with non-split node. For example, if $q \equiv 3 \bmod 4$, take the nodal cubic $Z(X^2+Y^2)=X^3$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$. So $\pi_1(X) \cong \widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ and $Gal(\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}/\mathbb{F}_q)$ acts on it by negation. Quotient $\pi_1(X_0)$ down to $(\pm 1) \ltimes \widehat{Z}$ (the infinite profinite dihedral group). Take $\alpha$ an $\ell$-adic integer not on the unit circle (for example, $1+\sqrt{2}$, and let $(\pm 1) \ltimes \widehat{Z}$ act by $\left( \begin{smallmatrix} \alpha^k & \\ & \alpha^{-k} \end{smallmatrix} \right)$ and 
$\left( \begin{smallmatrix} & \alpha^k  \\ \alpha^{-k} & \end{smallmatrix} \right)$ .

This example is slightly unsatisfying, since it becomes a direct sum of two pure sheaves if we extend the base field to $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$, but it works.

Comment: For $X_0 = {\rm{Spec}}(\mathbf{F}_q)$ we can define $\mathscr{G}$ corresponding to the homomorphism $\widehat{\mathbf{Z}} \rightarrow {\rm{GL}}_n(\overline{\mathbf{Z}}_{\ell})$ given by $1 \mapsto M$ with $M$  arbitrary.  So with $n>1$ pick $M$ whose eigenvalues are algebraic integers whose ratios do not lie on the unit circle under any archimedean absolute value.  This example can then be pulled back to any finite type $\mathbf{F}_q$-scheme you wish (and then tensored against whatever nonzero mixed sheaf you like).

Comment: @nfdc23 But then it isn't irreducible (at least over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{\ell}$). It splits as a direct sum of line bundles, one for each eigenvalue, each of which is pure, so the whole bundle is mixed.

Comment: @nfdc23 But you are making me realize that I need to specify $\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$ versus $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}}$. I intended the latter.

Comment: Thanks! That sounds like an answer -- conj 1.2.10 says there are no examples. I imagine this conjecture is still open?

Comment: With $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}_{\ell}$-sheaves there should be no counterexamples:  in 1.2.9 of Weil II it is conjectured by Deligne. [I deleted an earlier comment to which you refer, deducing 1.2.9 from Deligne's more refined conjecture 1.2.10 because I couldn't track down where Deligne makes a convention about writing "sheaf" to mean "Weil sheaf".]

Comment: Feel free to leave an answer if you'd like me to accept it, and thanks again!

Comment: I have vague memory that Lafforgue (for curves) and Drinfeld (in general) proved something towards this conjecture.  Before writing an answer (linking 1.2.9 to 1.2.10), I'd want to look at my copy of Weil II to remind myself if Deligne made his conjecture for lisse Weil sheaves or just lisse sheaves in the usual sense, since relating the general case to the "irreducible weight 0" case entails some twisting that a-priori leaves the framework of usual sheaves and requires working with Weil sheaves.  Maybe I'll find time next week (or someone else may take care of this in the meantime).